# errors while installing rasa stack

Tags: rasa

Am installing using anaconda thru conda prompt . I have a virtual environment and facing the following error. I think the httptools is the issue... need help guys

Building wheels for collected packages: httptools
      Building wheel for httptools (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\u94885\venv\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bbyaw4dy'
           cwd: C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\
      Complete output (30 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
      copying httptools__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
      copying httptools\parser\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
      copying httptools\parser__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
      running egg_info
      writing httptools.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to httptools.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to httptools.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      writing manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying httptools\parser\parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
      running build_ext
      building 'httptools.parser.parser' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\httptools
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\httptools\parser
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\vendor
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\vendor\http-parser
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\u94885\venv\env\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" /Tchttptools/parser/parser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\httptools/parser/parser.obj -O2
      parser.c
      C:\Program Files\Python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for httptools
      Running setup.py clean for httptools
    Failed to build httptools
    ERROR: sanic-plugins-framework 0.8.2.post1 has requirement sanic<=19.6.3,>=0.8.3, but you'll have sanic 19.9.0 which is incompatible.
    Installing collected packages: httptools, sanic, sanic-plugins-framework, sanic-cors, rasa-sdk, SQLAlchemy, rasa
        Running setup.py install for httptools ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\u94885\venv\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tz2l1g4g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\u94885\venv\env\include\site\python3.7\httptools'
             cwd: C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\
        Complete output (30 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
        copying httptools__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
        copying httptools\parser\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
        copying httptools\parser__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
        running egg_info
        writing httptools.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to httptools.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to httptools.egg-info\top_level.txt
        reading manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        writing manifest file 'httptools.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
        copying httptools\parser\parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\httptools\parser
        running build_ext
        building 'httptools.parser.parser' extension
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\httptools
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\httptools\parser
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\vendor
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\vendor\http-parser
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\u94885\venv\env\include "-IC:\Program Files\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" /Tchttptools/parser/parser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\httptools/parser/parser.obj -O2
        parser.c
        C:\Program Files\Python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\u94885\venv\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vnt9kp6d\httptools\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\u94885\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-tz2l1g4g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\u94885\venv\env\include\site\python3.7\httptools' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Try installing `python3-dev` via `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`. It should solve it, iirc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those viewed - I reinstalled python and it had some setup issues I guess. And the httptools issues is sorted out.. seeing other issues... :(